# browserSync.reload() hangs after reloading browser

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-browser-sync

I've created a watch for various file types, and all work perfectly except for html.  I instead of using `stream` I have to use `reload` to ensure that the changes show.  However, when I call `browserSync.reload` it reloads the browser but hangs.  The message in git-bash stays at

`[BS] Reloading Browsers...`

And all watchers stop working at that point.

Here is the code

```
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function () {
    watch([PATH_ALL_LESS], batch(function (events, done) {
        gulp.start('build:less', done);
    }));

    watch(['./client/**/*.ts', './client/**/*.js', './index-template.html'], batch(function (events, done) {
        gulp.start('watch-rebuild', done);
    }));

    watch(['./client/**/*.html'], browserSync.reload);
});
```